# What do these JavaScript color codes mean?

Tags: javascript, colors

When learning how to code on [Codecademy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codecademy), I found this code block in JavaScript:

```
// Color variables:
red = [0, 100, 63];
orange = [40, 100, 60];
green = [75, 100, 40];
blue = [196, 77, 55];
purple = [280, 50, 60];

// Letters in the message will cycle through these colors:
letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

message = 'Multiple colors!';

drawName(message, letterColors);
bounceBubbles();
```

What type of color code is this? I thought it was RGB, but its values goes up to 255, and therefore the color "purple" wouldn't be possible.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is `drawName`? Post a [MCVE]

Comment: Welcome on the SO! Sometimes a different scaling is used, but it looks for me a bug. Note, it is only an array, theoretically anything could be there, the program will be syntactically okay.

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/53385d4e8c1ccca3de00a9a6

Comment: On the codecademy exercise, "drawName" literally draws the message inside the parenthesis of this function with bubbles.

Comment: It is written right [in the article](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/53385d4e8c1ccca3de00a9a6) you pointed to: "*In this project we are using HSL (Hue, Saturation, Lightness). You can read about HSL and other color models [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Color_Models:_RGB,_HSV,_HSL).*" The first value is in degree and can be any number actually, since it will get modulated to 360.

Comment: But what is the *actual code*?

Comment: Ps: (It is in degree if you omit the unit, you can also set it to 'rad' in which case it would be modulated to 2π).

Comment: Thanks guys.

It was indeed HSL color code as suggested in the link that @chevybow shared.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Kaiido

Answer (score 0):

An RGB color value is specified with `rgb(red, green, blue)`.

Each parameter (red, green, blue) defines the intensity of the color as an integer between 0 and 255.

You will get the RGB values for the all different colors here: *[HTML Color Codes](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/html-color-codes.html)*

Comment: can also be defined as %. But anyway, the values in OP are for HSL, not RGB.